# I want to extract the maximum value among the duplicates

Tags: javascript

I want to remove duplicates of value, but I want to select the one with the maximum value of length.

```
let meary = [];
meary.push({ name: "aaa", value: 90, length: 3 });
meary.push({ name: "bbb", value: 90, length: 5 });
meary.push({ name: "ccc", value: 80, length: 3 });
meary.push({ name: "ddd", value: 0, length: 4 });
meary.push({ name: "eee", value: 0, length: 3 });
meary = meary.filter((ele, index, arr) => {
  // 重複削除
  const isa =
    arr.findIndex((item) => {
      if (item.value === ele.value) {
        if (item.length > ele.length) {
          return true;
        }
      }
      return false;
    }) === index;
  return isa;
});
console.log(JSON.stringify(meary));
```

This is the result i want

```
[
  { name: "bbb", value: 90, length: 5 },
  { name: "ccc", value: 80, length: 3 },
  { name: "ddd", value: 0, length: 4 }
]
```

This is the actual result obtained

```
[]
```

How do I write the code to get the result I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) out those items that have the same value and a smaller length than [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) other item in the array:

```js
const meary = [];
meary.push({ name: "aaa", value: 90, length: 3 });
meary.push({ name: "bbb", value: 90, length: 5 });
meary.push({ name: "ccc", value: 80, length: 3 });
meary.push({ name: "ddd", value: 0, length: 4 });
meary.push({ name: "eee", value: 0, length: 3 });

const result = meary.filter(
  (x, i, a) => !a.some(
    (y, j) => x.value === y.value && x.length < y.length && i != j
  )
);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Good use case for a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) which is more efficient to do look ups in than arrays

```js
const res = [...meary.reduce((a, c) => {
  const { length: len, value: val } = c;
  const ent = a.get(val);
  
  return (!ent || ent.length < len) ? a.set(val, c) : a;

}, new Map).values()];

console.log(res)
```

```html
<script>
const meary = [];
meary.push({ name: "aaa", value: 90, length: 3 });
meary.push({ name: "bbb", value: 90, length: 5 });
meary.push({ name: "ccc", value: 80, length: 3 });
meary.push({ name: "ddd", value: 0, length: 4 });
meary.push({ name: "eee", value: 0, length: 3 });

</script>
```

Comment: `O(n)` vs `O(n^2)`. I know which one I'd choose 